# How to fix "The given key was not present in the dictionary." Vb.Net Web Service

Tags: mysql, vb.net, web-services, database-connection

We are moving from an SIT Database to the production Database, after deploying the vb web services I figured out that the MysqlCommands are not filling my Dataset in certain cases and it gives error "The given key was not present int he dictionary".

Everything just works fine the SIT Environment but when we get to the production!

The dataset is not receiving the records when the query contains columns that don't have a charset&Collation value like the date columns.
Which means a query of `SELECT COUNT(*) from TableX` with one date column in TableX will give me an empty dataset

```vb
conn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=" & Conn_AdresseIP & ";" _
                      & "DATABASE=" & dataSource_BO & ";" _
                      & "UID=" & Tuser & ";" _
                      & "PWD=" & Tpass & ";" _
                      & "old guids=true;Convert Zero Datetime=true;" _ 
                      & "charset=utf8;" _
                      & "Allow User Variables=True"

file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\wamp\logs\test2.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("chaine : " & conn.ConnectionString)

conn.Open()
file.WriteLine("Conn opened ")
MyDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
file.WriteLine("adapterField")
MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet, "MyTable")
file.WriteLine("dataset filled")
conn.Close()
file.WriteLine("connexion closed")
```

I've checked the databse charsets values and i found some differences :

**SIT character_set_***

```
character_set_client,   utf8
character_set_connection,   utf8
character_set_database, utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem,   binary
character_set_results,  utf8
character_set_server,   utf8
character_set_system,   utf8
character_sets_dir, /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
```

**PROD character_set_***

```
character_set_client, utf8mb4
character_set_connection, utf8mb4
character_set_database, utf8
character_set_filesystem, binary
character_set_results, utf8mb4
character_set_server, utf8
character_set_system, utf8
character_sets_dir, /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/
```

I've tried everything like removing the `& "old guids=true;Convert Zero Datetime=true;" _`, or `& "Allow User Variables=True"`, or even leaving the Charset as default without specifying it to be utf8, but with no results